# Do sufficiently large Banach spaces admit non-compact operators with not too large range?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, set-theory, banach-spaces, operator-theory

As in the title,

> does there exist a cardinal number $\lambda$ such that for every Banach space $X$ of density/cardinality at least $\lambda$ there exists a non-compact bounded, linear operator $T\colon X\to X$ such that the range $T[X]$ has smaller density than $X$?

By *density* I mean the minimal cardinality of a dense set. This question could be strengthened and we may ask about non-compact operators with separable range.

Some remarks are in order.

1. In general, one cannot expect $T$ to be idempotent (a projection), at least under GCH. (See [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72321/decomposable-banach-spaces/233110#233110).)
2. Should the answer be positive, we would get for free examples of unital Banach algebras that are not isomorphic to Calkin algebras, that is, algebras of the form $B(X)/K(X)$, where $B(X)$ is the algebra of bounded operators on a space $X$ and $K(X)$ is the ideal of compact operators. (This suggests that it may be an open problem in the sense that it perhaps does not follow from a linear combination of known results.)
3. We lack examples of non-separable spaces $X$ for which this statement is false, that is potentially $\lambda$ could be $\omega_1$.