# Weak* HI Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The following question is inspired by Bill's  nice unpublished result that the dual of a non separable Banach space is decomposable.  (See the previous posts [**Decomposable Banach Spaces**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72321/decomposable-banach-spaces), [**Hereditarily indecomposable Banach spaces and Separable Quotient problem**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74171/hereditarily-indecomposable-banach-spaces-and-separable-quotient-problem)  and  [**A question related to the separable quotient problem**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413266/a-question-related-to-the-separable-quotient-problem).)

**Definition**: A dual Banach space $X^*$ is said to be $w^*$-HI if $\operatorname{dist} (S_Y,S_Z )= 0$ for every $Y$, $Z$ infinite dimensional $w^*$-closed subspaces of $X^*$. The space $X^*$ is said to be $w^*$-indecomposable if it is not the direct sum of two infinite dimensional $w^*$-closed subspaces.

**Question I**: Does there exist non separable $X$ such that $X^*$ is $w^*$-HI?

**Question II**: For $X$ HI is the second dual $X^{**}$ $w^*$-inecomposable?

There exists $X$ HI such that $X^*$ is non separable and $X^{**}= X \oplus l^2(2^N)$.

Comment: What ist $S_Y$?

Comment: The unit sphere of $Y$.

Comment: TeX note: please do not drop in and out of math mode in the middle of a formula.  For example, write $X^{**} = X \oplus l^2(2^N)$ `$X^{**} = X \oplus l^2(2^N)$`, not $X^{**}$= $X$ $\oplus$ $l^2(2^N)$ `$X^{**}$= $X$ $\oplus$ $l^2(2^N)$`.  (Notice the different appearance of symbols, and the difference in spacing.)  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for improving the presentation